# Importing OpenDocument into LyX 2.1.2

Tags: lyx, open-office

I'm trying to import `.odt` document into `LyX 2.1.2`. This throws the following error:

```
An error occurred while running:
w2l -clean
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry you're having this issue, but I feel obliged to tell you that, while LyX is very much on-topic for this site, not many people here use it.  I would recommend though that you follow the idea of a MWE and try to convert a *basic* ODT and then gradually add on 'features' until it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

LyX uses "converters" to import and export files. This converter is converting from ODT to LaTeX. LaTeX is something that LyX knows how to import, but the error is telling you that the command used by LyX to convert to LaTeX did not work. So first you have to figure that out. First confirm that `w2l` (writer2latex) is indeed installed on your system and accessible via the PATH. Then run the command manually (see if it has a verbose option, for example to debug). Once you get the command running, then you can either import the .tex file or you can change LyX's converter to run a different command (see Tools > Preferences > File Formats).